Pronounciation and casing
Me and my wife have young kids (one of which is 5) who are currently being taught English at school, we live in the UK.
She is under the belief that kids in the UK are taught in infant school that a capital a is pronounced “ay” (as in the name of the letter) and a lowercase a is pronounced “ah” (as in the phonetic pronunciation of the letter a).
I can’t find any reference to this, I’m fairly sure this is incorrect and that even at infant school level the casing of a letter has no link to how it is pronounced. Am I wrong? I’m aware of course of the phonetic alphabet e.g a = ay, b = buh etc etc, but don’t think this has any link in any way to the case of a letter.

You are correct.

Short A (á, æ, take your pick) is for apple. Long AY (Eh) is for 'orses. Well, that's what I was always told! :)

When I was in primary school (a long time ago!), I was taught to say 'ah, buh, kuh', which I found confusing because my parents had already taught me the alphabet using the 'ay, bee, cee' pronunciation.  The first one is considered more helpful for children learning  to read - case has nothing to do with it.

@KateBunting - I was bemused aged 8 when my sister, three years younger, and six months into her school career, pointed at the television (showing the letters 'BBC') and said -buh-buh-kuh', because my early school experience had taught me to say 'bee-bee-see'. This would have been sometime in 1960.

@KateBunting - I distinctly remember a poster in my (age 5) London County Council infants' school classroom, titled 'Poor g', showing a disconsolate personified lower-case 'g' sitting all alone . Outside the window were a bunch of kids having the kind of fun that children in 1957 had: - huntin', runnin', swimmin', playin'. But 'g' had been left behind! Teachers in those days felt their role included getting their little Cockney charges to 'talk proper'. By and large they failed, unless, as in my case, there was strong parental participation in that project.

No, there is no truth in this.
Children will be taught the "sound the letter makes" For example [æ] for the sound of the letter A or a, and the name of this letter is "A" [eɪ].  That "A" is a capital A (or "big A") and "a" is a small A. Later they will also be taught that the letter makes a different sound in some words and combinations; they'll learn to recognise particular digraphs such as "ay"=[eɪ] and "ar" = [ɑː].  They'll be taught to "sound out the letters" to read unfamiliar words.
They'll be taught to use "small" letters, except at the start of names and at the start of sentences, and they'll be taught how to join up the small letters.
The confusion probably arises as the uppercase letter "A" is most often seen in the "Alphabet posters" and read as "Ay", whereas the lowercase is the usual form in words and often read as [æ].  But there is no difference in pronunciation or name. And children will not be taught that there is a difference.

Of course, there's no accounting for what an individual teacher might be doing. If you want to know what you child's teacher is doing, the best way is to email them.

Thanks, I may check with the teacher but wanted to check I had not totally forgotten how I was taught when I was young, given my memory this is entirely possible!

Whether a letter is capital or small has absolutely no affect on how it should be pronounced.
We normally capitalize the first letter of a sentence and the first letter of proper names. The first letter of "major" words in titles and headlines are capitalized. We sometimes capitalize an entire word to show emphasis, or in dialog, to indicate that the speaker said it more loudly or forcefully. All other letters should be small.
The pronunciation of a word does not change when it is the first word of a sentence and therefore capitalized.
In English, many letters can have different sounds, depending on surrounding letters and conventions. I'm sure this is very confusing to people trying to learn English. It would be very nice if there was some easy way to tell where "a" should be pronounce "ah" or "ey" or "aah" or "eh", etc. But the rules are complicated, not as simple as just looking at capitalization.
